# How to display Meteor templates only for mobile?

Tags: mobile, meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like some templates to appear on mobile only. How can I do it in Meteor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no defined way for this in Meteor so the answer may fit any website :

- you can use [`Detectizr`](https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr) to get the kind of device used on the client. If it detects a mobile device you can set and pass a variable on which you will execute a different javascript code.
- in Meteor you can set `Session.set('mobile',true)` for example, so the client remembers it in all your app

Based on this, in Meteor you can write

```
var testDevice = function(){
    if ( Session.get('mobile') ) {
        //mobile version
        Router.go('mobileTemplate')
    }else{
        //desktop version
        ...
    }
} ;

Template.desktopTemplate.rendered = testDevice ;
```

Comment: Hello!I do not think it's necessary this plugin.You would not only use `Meteor.isCordova`? Apart from that I can not integrate this plugin in the Meteor. He is not in Atmosphere.I would not want to use the IronRouter. There is no native way? Anyway, thank you!

Sorry grammarians errors. I'm using Google Translate.

Comment: you can put it in client/compatibility. No indeed if you use cordova it is not necessary.

Comment: It is true. I did not let the question sufficiently clear. I'm sorry, I'm still learning to program. I'll accept your answer and open another topic. Thanks!